# Filter are not working in Android phones only in prestashop

Tags: php, jquery, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am have a store in prestashop. The filters in the category page are not working on Android mobiles only.

[image]

I have used a block-layered module.

My assumption is that the jquery module is not working well on the Android device.

Comment: Is there a code we can see?

Comment: Yes sure but you would like to see jQuery or php code?

Comment: jQuery would be more beneficial, actually that depends, who's filtering?

Comment: Here is jquery file url https://www.takivetaki.net/themes/rococo/js/modules/blocklayered/blocklayered.js

Comment: Problem is anroid phone is not calling the function of this jquery file. when i click on checkbox which are on left side it is calling this below jQuery.

Comment: $(document).on('click', '#layered_form input[type=checkbox], #layered_form input[type=radio]', function() {
        reloadContent(true);
    });

Comment: Can you assemble everything in JSFiddle or something?

Comment: I am not getting you what should i do? can you please guide me?

Comment: One more things i did some code like this       $(document).on('click', '#layered_form input[type=checkbox], #layered_form input[type=radio]', function() {
     alert('ho');
        reloadContent(true);
    });

Comment: Alert prompt came in desktop version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116426/discussion-between-yaron-and-aki).